# item aligning when resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web developing, and I'm learning how CSS works as I go along.
I'm creating a fun template to pass time but I noticed my aligning isn't right at all. When scrolling out or resizing browser everything goes way out of proportion. Any help on what's wrong and or what to improve with what I'm doing (again I'm new, so sorry)

I've tried other solutions and I couldn't get it to work. 
I directly linked my codepen example.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxWvJO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>OSRS - Template</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="scroll-middle"></div>
    <div class="scroll-top"></div>
    <div class="scroll-bottom"></div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Chat anytime on our discord">Button 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Get going!">Button 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Find out the VIP benefits!">Button 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="video">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/IcgB_OzA_sE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="discordapp">
      <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=488699973156864030&theme=dark" width="350" height="380" allowcontrols="true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>



/*
* Defines the body & html attributes
*/
body,
html {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  background-image: url(https://www.runescape.com/img/rsp777/bg2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*
* Defines the list attributes
*/
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*
* Defines the list attributes
*/
li {
  float: left;
  background-image: url(https://www.runescape.com/img/rsp777/splash/button_small.gif);
  top: 117px;
  height: 63px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 152px
}

/*
* Defines the list attributes
*/
li a {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
}

/*
* Defines the list attributes
*/
li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*
* Defines the container attributes
*/
.container-right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: silver;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 90%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*
* Defines the title attributes
*/
.title-box {
  text-align: center
}

/*
* Defines the logo attributes
*/
.logo {
  background-image: url(https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/4/41/Old_School_RuneScape_logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20170406224036);
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 175px;
  background-size: 250px 175px;
  top: 5%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.scroll-top {
  background-image: url(https://www.runescape.com/img/rsp777/grand_exchange/Scroll-Top.gif);
  position: absolute;
  width: 770px;
  height: 39px;
  background-size: 770px 39px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scroll-middle {
  background-image: url(https://www.runescape.com/img/rsp777/scroll/backdrop_745.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  position: absolute;
  width: 745px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 650px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scroll-bottom {
  background-image: url(https://www.runescape.com/img/rsp777/grand_exchange/Scroll-Top.gif);
  position: absolute;
  width: 770px;
  height: 39px;
  background-size: 770px 39px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bottom: -429px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.discordapp {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -565px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*
* Defines the flating attributes
*/
@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translatey(-20px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using positioning to layout everything (especially is you are using fiexed pixel values ) then it's very inflexible. There are much more modern and *automatically* responsive options available to you

Comment: care to list any of them??

Comment: You can try bootstrap

Comment: well the idea is to avoid that which i'm trying to do as you can see.

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you try out CSS flexes and grids, your code is missing fundamental formatting so when you resize the browser doesn't really know what to do and just moves things around.

Before trying more complex techniques I'd suggest you try to minimize your CSS, using breaks in HTML and understanding how to efficiently and non-redundantly center elements in your pages.

All and all, that's not the worst start, good luck with your learning process!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start from the end - unfortunately you can't except the same result with this code on every device. While it works on computer screens the problams start on smaller screens - mainly  because you are using absolute position and pixels unites.

The solution can be either breakpoints (css media query) so you can style differently depend on screen sizes, or to use percentage values (with min-width values), but that is not recommend with that code.

It's a good practice not using frameworks and code by yourself. You should learn html and css in order to gain more tools. I suggest start with w3schools and mdn, but there are lot of other guides out there...

By the way - it look very nice on my laptop! Good luck, and the most important - enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to see about [CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and [Media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp). this links with many tutorials/examples will help you to understand more about css and positioning. Because your code needs to adapt in every screen (mobile and desktops). your site looks good, keep coding!